# call instruction destroying stack

Tags: assembly, stack, nasm, x86-64, cpu-registers

I am writing a basic program in assembly code that is designed to print the numbers 1-10. My goal is to allocate two variables on the stack, one being the counter, the other being the end destination. I want to compare them, print them, increment the counter.

The problem I am having is that when I call the function printf, when it returns it is wiping the stack clean. I am not doing any kind of stack overflow or anything. I do not understand why the call to `printf` would destroy the stack at `$rsp-0x10` and `$rsp-0x20`

```
        global main
        extern printf

        section .text
main:
        push    rbp
        mov rbp, rsp
        sub rsp, 0x20
        mov qword [rsp-0x10], 0x0
        mov qword [rsp-0x20], 0xA
looper:
        mov rax, [rsp-0x10]         ; load the value on the stack (var 1) into the rax register
        inc rax                 ; increment the register
        mov qword [rsp-0x10],rax        ; copy the new value back to the stack
        mov rdi, message                ; load the address of the message string
        mov rsi, rax                ; load the second parameter which is the value of the counter var
        call    printf                  ; call printf. After this instruction the values at $rsp-0x10 and $rsp-0x20 are zero
        mov rax, [rsp-0x10]         ; ideally I would load the vars back up into rax and rbx
        mov     rbx, [rsp-0x20]
        cmp rax, rbx                ; then compare the variables and loop if they are not equal
        jne looper

done:
        leave
        ret

        section .data
message:    db  “%d”, 10, 0
```

Comment: x86-64 has 15 general-purpose integer registers (not counting RSP).  In the x86-64 SysV calling convention, RBP and RBX, and R12-R15 are call-preserved.  Use them instead of spilling to the stack!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use the red zone in leaf functions (that don't call other functions). Obviously if you issue a `call` that will itself already put a return address on the stack, and then the called function may also use the stack, just as you were allowed to use it.

On closer look I think you simply messed up the base register, you wanted to use `rbp` not `rsp` for addressing, since you allocated space in your stack frame. That space is below `rbp` but above `rsp`.

PS: `rbx` is a callee-saved register, you should preserve its value.
PS #2: as per the calling convention, varargs functions expect an upper bound on the number of vector registers used in `al`. Since `printf` is such a function, you should zero `al` before you call it.